# CLOS: Use a slot value to initialize another slot

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clos

I am pretty new to using CLOS. Here, I wrote one possible way of defining a Queue using CLOS:

```
(defclass Queue ()
    ((queue-size
        :reader queue-size
        :initarg :queue-size
        :initform (error "Provide a queue-size when initialising a Queue")
        :type number)
    (elements
        :accessor elements
        :initform (make-array queue-size :initial-element nil))
    (put-ptr
        :accessor put-ptr
        :initform 0
        :type number)
    (get-ptr
        :accessor get-ptr
        :initform 0
        :type number)))
```

As you can see, I use the value of the slot `queue-size` to make the array in the slot `elements`. But, unfortunately, this gives me the following error:

```
*** - DEFAULT-ELEMENTS: variable QUEUE-SIZE has no value
```

As I said, I am pretty new to CLOS. Is there any way I can still do this? Is it possible to overwrite some kind of init method? If yes, how do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In CLOS you can't directly refer to slots as variables. Also you can't refer to to other slots of the object in *initforms*.

The example, simplified:

```
CL-USER 27 > (defclass queue () (size elements))
#<STANDARD-CLASS QUEUE 4020001AB3>

CL-USER 28 > (describe (make-instance 'queue))

#<QUEUE 40200040CB> is a QUEUE
SIZE          #<unbound slot>
ELEMENTS      #<unbound slot>
```

We'll now set the `elements` slot:

```
CL-USER 36 > (defclass queue () ((size :initarg :size) elements))
#<STANDARD-CLASS QUEUE 42E0A2DBFB>
```

For that we write a `initialize-instance` `:after` method.
The usual initializing happens and *after* that our method runs. `WITH-SLOTS` allows us to use certain slots like variables in our code. Here we access the slots `size` and `elements`:

```
CL-USER 37 > (defmethod initialize-instance :after ((q queue) &rest initargs)
               (with-slots (size elements) q
                 (setf elements (make-array size :initial-element nil))))
#<STANDARD-METHOD INITIALIZE-INSTANCE (:AFTER) (QUEUE) 402000ADD3>
```

Without the *macro* `WITH-SLOTS`, using the *function* `SLOT-VALUE`, it looks like this:

```
CL-USER 38 > (defmethod initialize-instance :after ((q queue) &rest initargs)
               (setf (slot-value q 'elements)
                     (make-array (slot-value q 'size) :initial-element nil)))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 39 > (describe (make-instance 'queue :size 10))

#<QUEUE 402000BE0B> is a QUEUE
SIZE          10
ELEMENTS      #(NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Plus, I've learned something new about CLOS. Thanks!